# In AQL how to re-parent a vertex

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to re-parent an vertex.  I tried this but it seems not to have an effect

```
FOR c IN pm_child FILTER c._to == 'pmlibrary/48198494363' UPDATE c WITH {_from: 'pmattic/48212650139'} IN pm_child
```

When I look at the pm_child collection the _from field is untouched.  What is the correct way to modify an edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `_key`-attribute `_from` and `_to` [are system attributes and thus immutable.](https://docs.arangodb.com/Documents/index.html)

So, while you can specify them on creation of the document, you can't alter them later on.

You need to create a new document with the new `_from` and `_to` in order to achieve what you want.

[We're thinking about how queries could raise a warning](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1080) but didn't find a good solution for this yet.

I will give you an example how to do this [using the social graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html#the-social-graph) - Lets make **bob** a friend of **charly** and disconnect **bob** and **diana**. We need to create a new document were we [`MERGE`](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/DocumentFunctions.html) the existing edge and its new `_to`:

```
FOR rel IN relation FILTER rel._id == "relation/bobAndDiana"
  LET newRel = MERGE(rel, {_to: "persons/charlie",
                           _id:"relation/bobAndCharlie",
                           fieldToWhipe: null,
                           _key: "bobAndCharlie"})
  INSERT newRel IN relation RETURN newRel
```

And remove the original edge in another query (you may want to write a transaction for this):

```
FOR rel IN relation FILTER rel._id == "relation/bobAndDiana" REMOVE rel IN relation
```

Updating `_from` and `_to` directly will become possible with the ArangoDB 3.0 release.

Comment: Thank you for this and the quick and concise answers to all of my questions.  It is because of this support that I am thrilled with my foray into ArangoDB.

Comment: As a follow on to this question, I see that you have to create a new id and key in the merge.  Is there a way to let the system generate these or at least determine a guaranteed unique one to set it to?

Comment: FYI, in my case it was a bit easier, I just created a transaction to delete the existing edge and insert another one (since these edges don't have any additional fields).  Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words ;-> you need to put in a value with `null` which will cause the field to be un-set so the database can generate it for you. I've edited the query to demonstrate this.